# How to avoid sound delay in sound manager 2

Tags: javascript, audio, soundmanager2

I am using sound manager 2 for giving sound to my site.

My js code is :

```
function makesound(val) {
            soundManager.useHighPerformance = true;
            soundManager.useFastPolling = true;


            soundManager.setup({

                url: 'folder/sound',
                onclick: function() {
                    var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
                        id: 'aSound',
                        url: 'folder/sound/'+val
                    });
                    mySound.play();
                },
            });
        }
```

It makes sound. But the problem is there is a delay in sound..

How to avoid this problem?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can create the sound object or objects when the soundManager onload event fires, and make sure you set the autoLoad to true on the sound object.

```
soundManager.onload(function(){
    var sounds = [];
    var sound1 = soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'aSound',
        url: 'folder/sound/audio.mp3',
        autoLoad: true,
    });
    sounds.push(sound1);

    document.getElementById("playButton").addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        sounds[0].play();
    }, false);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the createSound function when the page loads, rather than in the click handler. This will enable to the sound file to load once, and before it's needed. At the moment you are reloading the sound file on every click (or at least, on the first click), and it needs time to download before it plays.

Comment: Can u give code for page onload in sound manager.. I am a fresher in it.